# Firebase profile integrations

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

What I am trying to do here is to implement a functionality on the start-up. I want my user's firebase  authentication email variable to set a variable that represents the current user logged into my app?

With the following code the line that sets the user variable works  after I click log in but not on page load! The console logs work perfectly on start-up  but not the setting of user to the email...

```
crossfitApp.controller('globalIdCtrl', ["$scope", 'defautProfileData',
  function ($scope, defautProfileData) {

    var dataRef = new Firebase("https://glowing-fire-5401.firebaseIO.com");
    //defautProfileData.country;

    $scope.authenticated = {
      currentUser: 10007,
      emailAddress: "",
      settings: "",

    };

    $scope.auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(dataRef, function (error, user) {
      if (error) {
        // an error occurred while attempting login
        console.log(error);
      } else if (user) {
        //Not working
        $scope.authenticated.currentUser = user.id;

        console.log('User ID: ' + user.id + ', ProvideFr: ' + user.provider + user);
        console.log(user);
      } else {
        console.log($scope.auth);
        alert('deuces');
        //!Trigger not logged in
      }
    });

  }
]); //GlobaldCtrl
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback to FirebaseSimpleLogin is not invoked inside the scope of Angular's [HTML compiler](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler). Normally, whenever you invoke ng-click, ng-submit, et al, Angular fires $scope.$apply(), which checks for any changes to the bound JavaScript variables and applies those to the DOM elements.

When an event outside of Angular changes a variable, you need to let Angular know by manually triggering a $apply event. The safest way to accomplish this is to use $timeout:

```
angular.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
   $scope.auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(dataRef, function (error, user) {
     if (error) {
       // an error occurred while attempting login
       console.log(error);
     } else if (user) {
       $timeout(function() {
          $scope.currentUser = user.uid;
       });
    } else {
       console.log('not logged in');
    }
});
```

In general, prefer user.uid to user.id, as it is unique across providers.

A library like [AngularFire](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire) can save you a lot of trouble, as it abstracts a lot of the complexities of integrating Firebase and Angular.